# Gradle: set variable in taskGraph.whenReady

Tags: gradle

My build script has this code:

```
def includePatchFrom = "WTF?!"

task patchWebXml(type: Exec) {
    executable "perl"
    args "scripts/patch.pl", includePatchFrom
}

gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->
    if (taskGraph.hasTask(webtestWar)) {
        includePatchFrom = "resources/webtest"
    }
    else {
        includePatchFrom = "resources/production"
    }
}
```

If I understand http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html correctly, I should be able to set that `includePatchFrom` variable in the `whenReady` closure, but it just keeps its initial value:

```
...
:patchWebXml
...
Starting process 'command 'perl''. Working directory: /Users/robert/ Command: perl scripts/patch.pl WTF?!
Successfully started process 'command 'perl''
Cannot read WTF?!: No such file or directory at scripts/patch.pl line 43, <$F> line 14.
:patchWebXml FAILED
```

From println statements I can tell that `includePathFrom` gets set to the correct value. It seems like the exec task already has used the old value of `includePatchFrom` and is not affected when the `whenReady` closure runs.

What am I missing here and how can I use a different patch file depending on whether this is a production or a test build?

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`taskGraph.whenReady` happens much later than the configuration of the task. By then it's too late to change the value of the variable. Instead, you'll have to (re)configure the task directly (`patchWebXml.args ...`).